# Strange behaviour of Object.keys(Obj[0]).map() :[] function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have this code in running, here I have given hard coded `[0]` value,
using this data in `<MaterialTable columns={Here using data for table} />`,
it should render only first row, but instead its rendering all rows after giving hardcoded `0`,

How this result into rendering all columns with all rows and iterating two time?

```
previewData = [
   {id: 1, name: "FileName", size: 15690, type: "doc", Date: "DDMMYY"}
   {id: 2, name: "FileName", size: 15690, type: "doc", Date: "DDMMYY"},
   {id: 3, name: "FileName", size: 15690, type: "doc", Date: "DDMMYY"},
   {id: 4, name: "FileName", size: 15690, type: "doc", Date: "DDMMYY"}
]


Object.keys(props.previewData[0]).map((x) => {
    if(x=="id"){return <div>{x}</div>}
) : []
```

Strange working code:

```
const columns = () => {
    return (
        props.previewData && props.previewData.length > 0 ?
        Object.keys(props.previewData[0]).map((x) => {
        if (props.Table && props.Table !== "nameTable") {
            if (x === "id"){
                return ({
                    title: ,
                    field: x,
                    width: "500rem",
                    sorting: false
                })// similar code for other fields also
// this code should gets called only once for array [0], its get iterated over from `.forEach()` from data of MaterialTable How???
       }
return (
    <MaterialTable
        title = ""
        icons={}
        options={{                
        }}
        columns={columns()}
        data={
            props.previewData && props.previewData.length > 0 ? props.previewData.map((row) => {
                const eachRowData = {};
                Object.keys(row).forEach((y) =>{                        
                })
                return eachRowData;
            }) : []
        }
    />
```

Comment: What's your actual goal? It feels like you've asked about X, but really wanted to ask about Y. See [What's the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for details.

Comment: "*instead its rendering all rows*" - what exactly does render where? Please share your complete code.

Comment: @Bergi all rows i mean, as i=0 is gets rendered but as well as 2,3,4 also get looped rendered, how this is happeing i have sent hardcoded 0 value

Comment: @AshishKamble No. Nothing in the code you posted does loop over the other rows. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys(props.previewData[0])` with your example `previewData` is:

```
["id", "name", "size", "type", "Date"]
```

Then you map those values to:

```
[<div>id</div>, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

because you've used `map` (not `filter`) and returned something only when the `x` parameter's value is `"id"`, which is only true for one of the five elements in the array.

It's not clear to me from your question what you want to do instead, but that's why you're getting an array with five elements rather than one. It almost seems like you're trying to filter so you only produce one `div`, but you're filtering based on a hardcoded value (`"id"`) which would mean you wouldn't need `map` at all, you'd just do:

```
<div>{props.previewData[0].id}</div>
```

Comment: it give me `[<div>1</div>, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined][<div>2</div>, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined][<div>3</div>, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined][<div>4</div>, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]` How this is happeingin in my case,  have used materialTable, its getting difficult to debug this code, although it code works as expected, im not getting How this is even working illogically?